# Catching global route changes in Nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'd like to catch an event where my route has changed. If the route has moved off of a specific URL, I'd like to handle that event and do something.

I'm finding this difficult to do with **Nextjs 13** and its app router implementation. Since best practice is to keep parent components as server components, I cannot use hooks until lower leaf components.

In an older version of Next (and its Pages Router), I would've used a `useEffect` with a depdendency for `useRouter` to capture the event in `_app.js`.

My parent `layout.js` is not rendered each time, and is also a server component.

How can I best capture route changes, globally using **App Router** and **Nextjs 13**?

Answer (score 0):

You can render a client component in your root `layout`, as a sibling to your other (potentially server-rendered) UI.

In your root layout:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <h1>Layout</h1>
        {children}
        <RouteChangeHandler />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

RouteChangeHandler:

```js
"use client";

import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export function RouteChangeHandler() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  useEffect(() => console.log(pathname), [pathname]);
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is a good idea. I wasn't thinking about a separate client component rendered in the root layout. I'm going to try implementing this and will mark answer as such, thank you.